# Xubuntu not booting after installed

Tags: xubuntu

Been trying to make Xubuntu work in a dell mini 1020, but after installation and updating the system and downloading the boot grub repair patch, still freezes at the Xubuntu logo initial screen.

Comment: What is boot grub repair patch?

Comment: hi there, found the problem some bug with the backlight:

sudo systemctl mask systemd-backlight@leds\:dell\:\:kbd_backlight.service